# Можно ли сделать поле, в которое можно вставить любой класс?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть необходимость сделать поле, в которое можно вставить любой класс, возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Зачем? Какой в этом смысл? Какая задача?

Comment: Просто надо сделать такое поле, дальше разберусь сам

Comment: Делай тип object, потом приводи его к нужному. Главное, следи, чтобы никто, кроме тебя этого не увидел. Если тебе это понадобилось, то ты явно что-то не так делаешь.

Comment: Учить обобщения, интерфейсы, наследование.

Comment: Тип object -- от него наследуется все

Comment: Нужно знать для каких целей, иначе и помощи не ждите, а вообще есть возможность такое реализовать